# "This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio" (VS2013)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently decided that I wanted to look at some of my old VS2013 projects from back in the day, so I installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 and attempted to open one of my old XNA projects. I was greeted with an "This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio" error on the .csproj file and a "The application is not installed" error on the .contentproj file. I made sure that the relevant SDKs for .NET and XNA were installed, but I still can't seem to get the project to open.

Comment: Have you tried with a recent version? In most cases, going forward is much easier than attempting to get such old versions running.